# Jetty sockets get closed on windows

Tags: jetty

After some time i started to get this warning error from jetty 9.4.51 on windows

```
WARN   [qtp1896974503-1047][] - java.io.IOException: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.close0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.close(SocketDispatcher.java:63)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.kill(SocketChannelImpl.java:878)
            at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.implDereg(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:613)
            at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.processDeregisterQueue(SelectorImpl.java:149)
            at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:186)
            at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
            at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectNow(SelectorImpl.java:105)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.nioSelect(ManagedSelector.java:183)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.select(ManagedSelector.java:200)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.select(ManagedSelector.java:605)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:542)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produceTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:362)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:186)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

And after a while i will get :

```
WARN   [qtp407261422-4877][] - Fatal select() failure java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:142)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.newSelector(SelectorManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.handleSelectFailure(ManagedSelector.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.select(ManagedSelector.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.select(ManagedSelector.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produceTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket operation on nonsocket: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:78)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:121)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76)
    ... 21 more
```

With that last warning jetty it will be dead and i need to restart the app.
I searched over the whole web and everywhere is related to vpn/firewall... but i need to know exactly what is the cause for this issue.
Anyone has any ideea?

Thanks,Alin.